# Is there an OS X program that shows a oscilloscope view of my system sound?

Tags: macos, audio

Title says it all. Is there a good way to see an oscilloscope view of my system sound?

Comment: Maybe combine a [VST host](http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2011/05/16/bpb-freeware-studio-best-free-vst-host-applications/) with a [oscilloscope plugin](http://bedroomproducersblog.com/2011/07/05/bpb-freeware-studio-best-free-oscilloscope-vstau-plugins/)?

Comment: [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/) isn't free, but you can use it forever with the nag screen and use its built-in Analysis/gfxscope and Analysis/gfxanalyzer, which are better than most of the standalone software I've tried (which isn't saying much).

Answer (score 2):

Most of actual audio edition programs supports the "oscilloscope mode", I mean, the feature that allows user to see the audio wave format(all of them are limited to 20Hz to 20KHz). Check the [Audacity software](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), there is a specific version for OSX, Windows and Linux that allows you to see the entire audio wave format:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't show the waveform in real time like an oscilloscope, and doesn't let you zoom in on higher frequency waves

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found any yet that listen to the system audio channels.  You can reroute system with [Soundflower](http://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/), however.  For the record here are two more handy OSX oscilloscope (and more) apps:

- [iSpectrum](http://dogparksoftware.com/iSpectrum.html) (free)
- [Electroacoustics Toolbox](http://www.faberacoustical.com/products/electroacoustics_toolbox/) (trial)

Answer (score 1):

What about something like [Blue Cat's Oscilloscope Multi](http://www.bluecataudio.com/Products/Product_OscilloscopeMulti/) ?

[image]

Comment: Looks great, but in my case I am just idly curious, and not ready to plunk down $50.

Answer (score 1):

Try the free app Oscilloscope!

https://asdfg.me/osci/

> A software oscilloscope made for looking at music. Drop an audio file
>   in the application and watch the waveforms.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blue Cat's Oscilloscope is a great VST which I have used for EQ but lacks in GUI! also is limited to its features. VST plugin by Melda Production such as the [MAutopitch](https://www.producersbuzz.com/downloads/download-free-vst-plugins/mautopitch-free-pitch-correction-vst-plugin/) or [MAutopan](https://www.meldaproduction.com/MAutopan) are great, to be more relevant, mEQ and mOSC you can check out! 1 download has like 40 Free Bundle plugins it's probably one of the best Free VST's you will find out there.

You could try using;

1. MAutoDynamicEq
2. MSpectralDynamicsLE

See how you get on :)

Here are 2 more links you can check out, hope they help :)

- [80+ Free VST VST Plugins](https://www.producersbuzz.com/category/downloads/download-free-vst-plugins/)
- [30 of my top used VST plugins](https://www.producersbuzz.com/top-30-most-popular-free-vst-plugins-on-producersbuzz-2022/)